# Change last loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to output some numbers, all separated with a comma. In the following code also the last number will be "separated":

```
for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
   cout << i << ",";         
}
```

Is it possible to avoid that?

So instead of `1,2,3,` I want just `1,2,3`

Comment: Classic homework problem.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. No need to downvote.

Comment: @user1170330 What if I say that you haven't put sufficient amount of effort into solving this yourself? Then the downvote is suddenly justified.

Comment: @user1170330 Just an observation.  I didn't downvote.

Comment: W'hat have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tend to do in such cases:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (i > 1) cout << ", ";
    cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. However, I tend to avoid this type of if-statement within a loop when iterating over many elements since the evaluation of the condition takes some extra work, rather than just printing the last element by itself after the loop and looping over *n-1* elements in the loop instead.

Comment: @VictorZamanian I think the compiler is smart enough to LICM that out :)

Comment: According to my quick testing, no it isn't. :-| At least not `clang` on Mac OS X v10.7.5. Maybe I should be using a smarter compiler. :-)

Comment: @Victor Zamanian: Usually the CPU is smart enough to make correct guess. I remember being demonstrated a loop with `if` (to skip an iteration in the middle) which worked faster than two equivalent loops.

Answer (score 4):

You have to put comma in diffrent place, like this:

```
const int n = 5;
int tab[n] = {1,2,3,4,5};

if(n >= 1) 
    cout << tab[0];
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    cout<<", "<<tab[i];
```

Link to [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8b8PMg), where code can be executed.

Comment: Surprisingly, it's not quite an obvious trick. However, in more tricky cases it appears more often: for example, I've seen SQL query builder where its `WHERE` clause always started with `WHERE 0=0`, so appending new filters was straightforward `where_clause += "AND <condition>"`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to write the last (or first) number by itself:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << i << ",";
}
cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: `cout << i; for(i = 2; i < 3; i++) cout << "," << i; cout << endl;` is slightly better, because checking before starting the loop is easier than undoing/preventing the last iteration. Especially if loop exit conditions can't be predicted.

Comment: It would seem to me that, if checking is necessary, it would be equally simple to check the first element as the last. I can't see why it would be easier to prevent the first element to be printed than the last. The for loop condition should in many cases also stop elements from being printed, in my experience. BTW, for completeness: I think you meant `i <= 3` in the for loop condition.

Comment: Imagine we iterate not over the range of integers; but, say, over `std::vector<std::string> v`: `for(auto it = v.cbegin(), eit = v.cend(); it != eit; ++it) { cout << *it << ","; }` . What should I change `it != eit` to?

Comment: Well, if you know already that the vector isn't empty, follow this: 1) Declare `it` and `eit` outside the loop, and init `eit` to `v.cend()`. 2) Do `eit--`. ("All standard containers support at least bidirectional iterators types." - cplusplus.com) 3) Continue as I did in the answer above but with iterators, with the same loop condition as you used. (Just don't re-init `eit` in the for loop, as you have done.) Works like a charm.

Comment: Ha. So you cheat and use the ability to go back. Okay, now repeat this trick with `for (istream_iterator<string> it(cin), eit; it != eit; ++it) { cout << *it << ","; }` , would you please? And by the way, `std::forward_list` and `std::unordered_set` are standard containers supporting strictly `ForwardIterator`. And there are non-standard, third-party, problem-specific containers which don't support `BidirectionalIterator` either.

Comment: What I am trying to persuade you is that giving special treatment to the first element is easy and has no underwater rocks. Giving special treatment to the *last* element only seems to be equally easy.

Comment: I don't see how that's cheating. I also don't know if you're joking or if you really want me to try it, but I should tell you that in that instance it is impossible because the number of "elements" is not known until *after* the last element has been entered (by running into `EOF` e.g.). We'd have to delete the last comma instead. You didn't have to persuade me of that either. I already said they should be equally simple in my first comment, except for when it is impossible. But these impossible cases are quite rare in my opinion, to be perfectly honest. I personally prefer the "after" method.

Comment: Oh well. I just thought that if I persuade one more programmer of a good practice, that would mean there is one more programmer using the good practice. The "before" method takes the same amount of code as the "after" method, but doesn't have its limitations, that's all.

Comment: I suppose it's all a definition of "good practice" in the end.

Answer (score -2):

Your loop runs three times. If you write a comma every time, you're gonna get three commas. If you don't want the last comma, you can just use an if statement to not write it. Your loop could be:

```
cout << i;
if(i < 3)
cout << ",";
```